# Pixel data unpacking to smaller sections

Tags: c++, for-loop, offset

I'm trying to write a function that unpacks an image into separate quads. But for some reason the results are distorted (kinda stretched 45 degrees), so I must be reading the pixel array incorrectly, though I can't see the problem with my function...

The function takes 2 unsigned char arrays, "**source**" and "**target**" and two unsigned int values, the "**width**" and "**height**" of the source image. Width is dividable by 4, and height is dividable by 3 (both return the same value, because the texture is 600 * 450) so each face is 150*150 px. So the w/h values are correct. Then it also takes in 2 ints, "**xIt**" and "**yIt**" which determine the offset - which 150*150 block should be read.

Here's the function:

```
    const unsigned int trgImgWidth  = width  / 4;
    const unsigned int trgImgHeight = height / 3;

    unsigned int trgBufferOffset = 0;

    // Compute pixel offset to start reading from
    unsigned int Yoffset = yIt * trgImgHeight * width * 3;
    unsigned int Xoffset = xIt * trgImgWidth  * 3;

    for (unsigned int y = 0; y < trgImgHeight; y++)
    {
        unsigned int o = Yoffset + Xoffset;                // Offset of current line of pixels

        for (unsigned int x = 0; x < trgImgWidth * 3; x++) // for each pixel component (rgb) in the line
        {
            target[trgBufferOffset] = source[o + x];

            trgBufferOffset++;
        }
        Yoffset += width * 3;
    }
```

Anyone see where I might be going wrong here?

Comment: Build yourself a really stupid bogus image with all of the "pixels" containing a number generated from their position and run it through your function in a debugger. When you see the code grabbing the wrong pixel backtrack to where the coordinates were computed and look at the inputs to the formula. If that doesn't solve the problem, work back further until you see where you are getting the wrong outputs.

Comment: What did you observe when [debugging](http://idownvotedbecau.se/nodebugging/) your code? Ah, and what actually went wrong? Mind to [elaborate](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/48796597/edit) please?

Comment: @user4581301 That's borderline _"rude"_.

Comment: @TheDude Might be. I just outlined what I would do: Set up an experiment and the walk through the code until I found the math error or bad assumption I'd made.

Comment: @user4581301 Lead me down the _rabbit's hole_ to pop up at the _mad hatter's teaparty_?

Comment: Don't worry I understood what you meant, I was thinking of doing that as I went to grab a bite :P I'll do it now an come back to you guys, thanks in advance!

Comment: @GDN9 Don't get lost in _loopholes_!